# MetaMask expose accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask

[From 2nd November MetaMask](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) will not expose user accounts by default anymore and we must do it. 
I'm confused about how we are supposed to integrate that in our dapps.

For example, I have a standard web3.js file with the following code:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';



let web3;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // metamask is running
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  //user is not running metamask
  // create provider through infura
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    // pass url of remote node
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/censored'
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);

}
export default web3;
```

Should changes be in the web3.js file? Or, should I create a button on the website which must be clicked by the user to give me access to his MetaMask account?

Comment: Hi @cristian now you have to request access to the user accounts. You can see what the changes are and how to implement this here https://medium.com/metamask/eip-1102-preparing-your-dapp-5027b2c9ed76

Comment: I think it will be different for every app, but in general the medium article explains it quite well.

Comment: I need further explanation. I still don't get it in full, or at least I don't feel confident with the information that has been provided. Do I have to use Ethereum.enable() for EVERY web3 call???? Or can I just call it once and MetaMask will remember it for users?

Comment: [https://medium.com/coinmonks/tutorial-how-to-connect-a-javascript-front-end-to-a-smart-contract-6af4bdf45f7a](https://medium.com/coinmonks/tutorial-how-to-connect-a-javascript-front-end-to-a-smart-contract-6af4bdf45f7a) explains it in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! You most likely have a web3.js file that you export to your default app.
The solution is simple:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';



let web3;
if (window.ethereum) {
  // metamask is available
  window.ethereum.enable();    
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  //user is not running metamask
  // create provider through infura
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    // pass url of remote node
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/censored'
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);

}
export default web3;
```